# Maven - package linked resources

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a project that has linked resources to it. These linked resources are provided in maven Pom file like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <linkedResources>
            <linkedResource>
                <name>src/main/webapp/Manual.pdf</name>
                <type>1</type>
                <location>C:/location/Manual.pdf</location>
            </linkedResource>
....
</plugin>
```

on execution `mvn eclipse:eclipse`  , these resources now appear under my eclipse working tree dir (as well as inside .project properties file). However how do i package these resources using `mvn package`, so they appear in my war file?.

Thanks

Comment: Check out the [Maven WAR plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html) and the <packagingIncludes> attribute.

Comment: @cy3er so i have to explicitly define the same paths in war-plugin ?